# How to redirect to same page with parameters given as json

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site i am using jQuery's ajax this way:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: productSearch.searchUrl,
        data: parameter,
        dataType: 'json'
    }
```

"data" contains all parameters.

On some state i want to redirect the user to the same page but with all paramters from "data" appended.

Example

```
data = {
    "par1" = "value1",
    "par2" = "value 2"
}
```

current url: `www.google.com`
should be redirected to `www.google.com?par1=value1&par2=value2`.

How to do this (with jQuery?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var data = {
    "par1": "value1",
    "par2": "value 2"
}
var params = $.param(data);
if (location.href.match(/\?/)) {
    location.href += params;
} else {
    location.href += '?' + params;
}
```

Comment: could you please explain a little (esp. "/\?/")

Comment: the if check if there are already parameters, if they are there will be ? in url.

Answer (score 3):

with simple javascript

```
window.location.href = "www.google.com?" + Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
  return key + "=" + data[key];
}).join("&");
```

And yes, data key can be encoded as well

```
window.location.href = "www.google.com?" + Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
  return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
}).join("&");
```

Comment: @dermoritz sorry for delayed reply, I have added code to take care of encoding as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) will serialize an object like that. Then you just append the resulting string to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
params = $.params(data);
window.location.href = window.location.href +'?'+params;
```

Comment: Check my answer @rafaelcpalmeida

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida  i added the hardcoded solution as the intial answer, and was preparing for the dynamic solution, but damn, people are so fast  here to down vote an answer!